# Scrapy not filling form

Tags: html, scrapy

I am trying to get Scrapy to fill the following HTML form using FormRequest.from_response :

```
  <form class="form-horizontal" method="POST" role="form">
    <div class="form-group">
        <label class="col-sm-3 control-label" for="inputEmail3"> Username </label>
        <div class="col-sm-9">
            <input class="form-control" value="" maxlength="32" name="pun" />
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label class="col-sm-3 control-label" for="inputEmail3"> Passphrase </label>
        <div class="col-sm-9">
            <input class="form-control" type="password" value="" maxlength="10000" name="ak" />
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
</div>
<div align="right">
    <input id="send" type="submit" value="Login" name="login" />
</div>
```

I followed the tutorial [here](http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/request-response.html),  but the code there with the fields "ak" and "pun" is not working. Any ideas or suggestions? Thanks.
EDIT: This is what I got so far

```
class TestSpider(CrawlSpider):

    name = "test1"
    allowed_domains = ['...']
    start_urls = [
        '...'  
    ]

    rules = {Rule(LinkExtractor(), callback='parse_items', follow=True),}

    def parse_items(self, response):
            return [FormRequest.from_response(response,
               formdata={"pun": '...', "ak": '...'},
               callback=self.after_login)]

    def after_login(self, link):
        # Check login succeed before going on
        if "authentication failed" in response.body:
            self.log("Login failed", level=log.ERROR)
            return
        # Crawl contents ...
```

Comment: Can I get the start-url ?

Comment: The link is .onion one, so I don't know if I can share it publicly. If a moderator allows me I will.

Comment: As ashkufaraz pointed out, the problem could be caused by the fact that the button is outside the form. So I added clickdata = {"name": 'login'} to the FormRequest.from_response(...). Unfortunately the crawler isnt working still. Any suggestions guys ???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved the issue. All that was needed was simply to write:

```
formdata={"pun": '...', "ak": '...', "Login" = 'login'}
```

However I am still doubtful about the reason behind it. Can anyone please explain?

Answer (score 0):

`submit` button must be  in the  `<form>` tag

TRY THIS

```
<form class="form-horizontal" method="POST" role="form">
    <div class="form-group">
        <label class="col-sm-3 control-label" for="inputEmail3"> Username </label>
        <div class="col-sm-9">
            <input class="form-control" value="" maxlength="32" name="pun" />
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label class="col-sm-3 control-label" for="inputEmail3"> Passphrase </label>
        <div class="col-sm-9">
            <input class="form-control" type="password" value="" maxlength="10000" name="ak" />
        </div>
    </div>
    <div align="right">
        <input id="send" type="submit" value="Login" name="login" />
    </div>
</form>
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply but what I am trying to do is adapt che code here http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/request-response.html#using-formrequest-from-response-to-simulate-a-user-login  to this scenario, since using it directly does not work in my case. Thanks again for the help :)